# Accessing "old" ("previous date") Pansharpened Landsat data in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, landsat, pansharpening

A few months ago I found an excellent pansharpened Landsat dataset to use as a basemap in ArcGIS by going to the Add Data icon, selecting ArcGIS Online and then selecting add pansharpened landsat. However, when I re-open the MXD now (a few months later), I see a new pansharpened landsat basemap – most likely from a more recent image. The new image is useless for this specific area as it contains many clouds.

Does anyone know if there is any way that I can access the old (previous date) pansharpened landsat basemap?

What would I do to access a certain date?

Or is there any way that this can be downloaded somewhere else and brought into ArcGIS?

I know where to download the regular landsat imagery but I am not sure about the pansharpened imagery.

Comment: Have you tried using the Time tab in the Landsat 8s Layer Properties?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Johns! I have never used the Time tab before. I was able to enable it however, how do I use it to switch the imagery from one month to the next? Do I need to enable a certain window or toolbar?

Comment: You have to enable time on the L8 layer and set a time step interval in Properties.  Then bring up the time slider window (if you don't have a button out for it use customize and search for time slider) and in the options on it set a time period you will be looking at (e.g. 10 days).  Then move the slider to move that time period around for different imagery dates.  Give it time to load.

Comment: Thanks Johns! Unfortunately I am still unable to get this to work. I did what you said and I also did some research on the time slider (this function was not available when I took GIS courses so I don't have much experience with it). I am able to open the time slider window and move it from date to date. I can also edit the properties. However the satellite imagery does not appear - it is blank. I have given it lots of time to load. Any ideas please?

Comment: It is not a user friendly UI.  When you look at your time slider options, you should have a time step interval set, a time window set and a time window option drop down selected.  To start with try 10 days and display data for entire time window.   Then when you click the back or forward arrows you will see the time period it is showing, and as you click from one period to the next if it finds an image the "drawing globe" should appear.  Since you have a target date in mind you will want to start near it and then step through it.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help. Unfortunately I had already tried everything you mentioned before posting yesterday and it is still blank. The drawing the glob icon has never appeared. My guess is that this has something to do with how the Time Field (Acquisition Date) is set up for this data set in the attribute table but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: Well, there's always opening a new project, bringing in one layer, and then trying the Landsat 8.  Whenever ArcMap doesn't work right I try the new project approach.  You might also try ArcGIS Pro if you've installed it.  The default setup works a little better than ArcMap's although I think I had to manually "split" the slider with the mouse to form the time window, which wasn't obvious to me at first.

Answer (score 1):

You can download Landsat imagery directly for free from a number of sources online.  The GLOVIS server (http://glovis.usgs.gov/) is excellent as you can specify what the acceptable cloud cover percentage is in increments of 10%.  You can specify Landsat 8 or 7 (I never use 7 any more due to the gaps).

By default it'll give you the most recent image that meets your criteria.  You can then scroll through earlier images using the previous button.

It's easy to both combine the bands and pansharpen in ArcMap.

Doing it this way you're not tied to a perpetually changing online basemap, nor do you need to be online to use the images once you've downloaded them, unlike using an online basemap.